# Force .htaccess in subdomain to return response 200 for OPTIONS request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cross-domain, subdomain

I have a subdomain https://sub.domain.com, which return 403 forbidden for OPTIONS request. I want to force the response to 200 in .htaccess and I don't have access to the root .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Force to request 200 for options
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule .* / [R=200,L]
```

This code doesn't work in my case

Comment: I would want to know where in your config these requests are being blocked. It may not be possible to override this in `.htaccess`? "This code doesn't work" - what actually happens? What response are you getting with that code?

Comment: I just contacted the manager of the main domain and he told that he disabled this request. Can I add some code in the htaccess of the subdomain to override his code?

Comment: Probably not - I expect the request is not even reaching your `.htaccess` file. What happens when you use the above code in `.htaccess`? I would expect you to get an "error" response with a 200 OK status. If you are still seeing a 403 Forbidden then the code isn't even being processed.

Comment: Mmm yeah right!